# phpmailer exim неверный IP отправителя (bindto)

Tags: php, exim, phpmailer

php скрипт через phpmailer(v.5.2.23) отправляет письмо через Exim(v.4.89) с базовым конфигом:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => "XXX.XXX.58.34:0",
    ),
);
```

Но при этом в заголовках сервера два поля Received, первое с master_ip сервера, а второе с тем что я указал в bindto. Если bindto не указывать то используется IP SMTP хоста, и все равно есть заголовок с мастер IP и из-за этого неверно отрабатывает проверка DKIM.

заголовки письма:

```
Received: from mxfront5g.mail.yandex.net ([127.0.0.1])
    by mxfront5g.mail.yandex.net with LMTP id 5Dd73rG1
    for <user@yandex.ru>; Thu, 22 Jun 2017 13:46:13 +0300
Received: from master_ip_domain.ru (master_ip_domain.ru [XXX.XXX.120.136])
    by mxfront5g.mail.yandex.net (nwsmtp/Yandex) with ESMTPS id 1uFg4tsd66-kDuGWZn8;
    Thu, 22 Jun 2017 13:46:13 +0300
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits))
    (Client certificate not present)
Return-Path: noreply@domain.ru
X-Yandex-Front: mxfront5g.mail.yandex.net
X-Yandex-TimeMark: 1498128373
Authentication-Results: mxfront5g.mail.yandex.net; spf=softfail (mxfront5g.mail.yandex.net: transitioning domain of domain.ru does not designate XXX.XXX.120.136 as permitted sender, rule=[~all]) smtp.mail=noreply@domain.ru; dkim=pass header.i=@domain.ru
X-Yandex-Spam: 1
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=domain.ru; s=dkim; h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:
    MIME-Version:Message-ID:Subject:From:To:Date:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:Content-ID:
    Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc
    :Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:
    List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
    bh=SSg1RYgWoJvoRis8urjLzW2ysCw6ESEuk73wKcVuEao=; b=tQAWb0hPYqibdoAwVSwrsbuIZO
    ngP/MTtFxn+fS9N6G1XqEZbIh3cc/+gcVeXe2CSQxcpjFX/K3DICtk8Gb9Z0q1ekqS1S+I2GEY3HP
    JJqKTX/HS47t1PfF3xBDVjlezvvhrbuil+zW2a1lxn45jqOxJPySPvmjzZLiIgB/+7QM=;
Received: from mx.domain.ru ([XXX.XXX.58.35] helo=www.domain.ru)
    by mx.domain.ru with esmtp (Exim 4.89)
    (envelope-from <noreply@domain.ru>)
    id 1dNzcr-0001ou-Dq
    for user@yandex.ru; Thu, 22 Jun 2017 13:46:13 +0300
```

Подскажите, как исправить? нигде не могу найти способ решения этой проблемы с настройками Exim...

Comment: вижу три, а не два заголовка received. // а вообще: https://serverfault.com/a/776606/292034

Answer (score 0):

например, можно просто удалить все заголовки `received` при отправке сообщения на внешний smtp/smarthost.

тогда, если исходить из вашего пример, первого по времени (или последнего по порядку) заголовка `received` вообще не будет (того, что начинается с `Received: from mx.domain.ru ([XXX.XXX.58.35] helo=www.domain.ru)`).

для этого, как [подсказывают](https://serverfault.com/a/776606/292034), нужно добавить директиву

```
  headers_remove = received
```

в секцию

```
remote_smtp:
```

или (если используете smarthost) в секцию

```
remote_smtp_smarthost:
```

---

это решение может не подойти, если ваш smtp используется как прокси для какой-нибудь почты, приходящей из внешнего мира: полная история движения сообщения иногда может потребоваться. в таком случае стоит воспользоваться [более сложным вариантом](https://serverfault.com/a/565759/292034).

Comment: нет, это все не работает. 
У меня в конфиге есть
 remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  interface = <;${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$sender_address_domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domainips}}}} 

а в файле domainips привязки домена к ip. Для домена создано две привязки с разными IP. Но используется только первая. 
Как можно заставить exim обрабатывать их? Может как то отдельный роут сделать или еще что?